# How to search using Prestashop web service

Tags: search, prestashop

I'm trying to use Prestashop's web service to build an app for my store. For searching products, it's known that we can use

```
http://store_url/api/search?query=keywords&language=1
```

But if I search for anything, it won't give me more than 10 results. I've tried using `&limit` and `&display`. But nothing works.

If there's an alternative, please let me know.

Comment: Have you looked on their [API documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Using+the+REST+webservice)?

Comment: Yes, I have. But their documentation on web service is incomplete to say the least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much wall smashing, I've found a work around. So, the problem is in this file located at /classes/webservice,

```
WebserviceSpecificManagementSearch.php
```

Around line 87, you'll find

```
$results = Search::find($this->wsObject->urlFragments['language'], $this->wsObject->urlFragments['query'], 1,1, 'position', 'desc', true, false);
```

This the last but second argument tells the Search function that it's an ajax search. **MAKING IT FALSE WILL NOT WORK**.

Instead, you need to go to /classes/Search.php and find the function "find". Starting at around line 278, you'll find this:

```
if ($ajax)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT p.id_product, pl.name pname, cl.name cname,
                    cl.link_rewrite crewrite, pl.link_rewrite prewrite '.$score.'
                FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product p
                INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl ON (
                    p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                    AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').'
                )
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang` cl ON (
                    product_shop.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category`
                    AND cl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('cl').'
                )
                WHERE p.`id_product` '.$product_pool.'
                ORDER BY position DESC LIMIT 10');
        return $db->executeS($sql);
    }
```

As you can see, the results are limited by 10. So you need a way to tell the function that it's being called by the WebService. So what I did was this. It's pretty simple. Instead of

```
ORDER BY position DESC LIMIT 10'
```

use:

```
ORDER BY position DESC LIMIT '.(($isWS)? '10000': '10')
```

The variable $isWS is type Boolean. So you'll have to change the find function's declaration to this:

```
public static function find($id_lang, $expr, $page_number = 1, $page_size = 1, $order_by = 'position',
    $order_way = 'desc', $ajax = false, $use_cookie = true, Context $context = null, $isWS = false)
```

Once you've done this, you can now pass in the value for $isWS from WebserviceSpecificManagementSearch. So change it to this at line 87:

```
$results = Search::find($this->wsObject->urlFragments['language'], $this->wsObject->urlFragments['query'], 1,1, 'position', 'asc', true, false, null, true);
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can try this way to search products:

```
http://store_url/api/products/?display=full&limit=2&filter[name]=[print]%
```

You can change `display` and `limit`.

It's from [Prestashop web services doc](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Chapter+8+-+Advanced+use).

Hope this helps anyone.